# Linux SoftLink to applications and execution

Tags: linux, symlink

I have created a softlink to an application using the following command:

```
ln -s sourcedir/Application somedir/ApplicationSoftLink
```

But I do not know how to start the application using the softlink. My understanding of a softlink is that it is the same as a shortcut in Windows, you just double-click the shortcut and the application will launch. However, when I tried to `./ApplicationSoftLink` the application would not start.

Could someone please provide some assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ln -s sourcedir/Application somedir/ApplicationSoftLink` probably puts the wrong path in your symbolic link.

Try:

```
ln -s $PWD/sourcedir/Application somedir/ApplicationSoftLink
```

Answer (score 0):

Were you in somedir when you tried running ./ApplicationSoftLink?

I think what you want to do is create the link in some directory in your path, so you don't have to say where the file is at all.  You can type

```
echo $PATH
```

to find out what's in your path.  **/usr/local/bin** is a good choice for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

is sourcedir/Application executable?

> when I tried to "./ApplicationSoftLink" the application would not
>   start.

Is there any error message?

were you typing `./ApplicationSoftLink` under "`somedir`"?

or try `ln -s /absolute/path/sourcedir /absolute/path/you/want/somedir/myApp`
then under `somedir/myApp/`  run `./Application`